# Getting [ERROR] KeyError: 's3' in Lambda fuction when trying to execute a transcribe job on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am getting a Keyerror in my logs when trying to invoke a AWS transcribe on files uploaded to my bucket with mp3 extension.

My bucket sends a notification to an SQS (this might not be the best architecture however its the requirements and I sadly have no control)  which then invokes the lambda trigger however I keep hitting the same error. I have tried several of the fixes and have landed on the code below however still no joy .. Anyone know what the issue could be? Am I missing something?

For info the requirement is for each file uploaded to s3 this sends a message to SQS which then triggers the lambda function. This function transcribes the file and saves back to output bucket.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        job_name = context.aws_request_id


        transcribe.start_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName = 'job-name',
                                            LanguageCode='en-GB',
                                            MediaFormat='mp3',
                                            Media = {
                                            'MediaFileUri': f'https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/s3://{bucket}/{key}'
                                            },
                                            OutputBucketName='bucket-name'                                            
                                        )
```

This is full error -
[ERROR] KeyError: 's3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 105, in lambda_handler
bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']

Could it be because I am invoking the lambda from SQS and not S3? If so what would be the work around? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: "Could it be because I am invoking the lambda from SQS and not S3?" Yes absolutely! You should start by logging the `event` object to see what shape it is.

Comment: The message from S3 will be wrapped by an SQS message. You can see the content by looking at the `event` record passed to the Lambda function. You'll need to use `json.loads(message)` to convert the string message into an object. Alternatively, you could have S3 trigger the Lambda function directly, without going via SQS.